# Push Plugin for ANDROID IONIC 2 not working in prod mode, but works in dev mode

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, production-environment

[The very same code working fine in dev mode..getting pushes. but in prod build iam getting the error push plugin not installed.Check the below image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMqIE.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.. The problem is that i have called Push.init before platform.ready. Once i enclosed it inside the success callback of platform.ready it is working now.

Comment: Thank you, i had the same problem with the file and filetransfer plugin which worked fine in development mode but gave an error of 'missing plugin' in production mode. switching their initialization untill after platform ready fixed it for me too. I also had an initialization in a constructor of a service i needed to change but everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do build prod with this plugin. looks like the plugin isn't part of the build that you did.

Comment: No the plugin is added in both config.xml and package.json. I havent changed any code. If i run ionic run android it works ,, the same code if i use ionic run android --prod.. it is not working.. is it any problem with AOT compiler.. or ami missing something in prod build?

Comment: can you maybe try run build via cordova?

Comment: ya when i do cordova run android , push is working.. but i need to compress my js and css, ngc and AOT for performance improvement which can be achived through ionic run android --prod

Comment: If i use uncompressed version of main.js it is working..if I use compressed version it is not working

Comment: it hard to find the issue, but I think you may see what steps did you miss from this tutorial https://ionicframeworkapps.wordpress.com/2016/05/18/how-to-implement-push-notifications-in-an-android-ios-app-using-ionic-framework/